# GitHub v4 API: Calculate content specific reaction count on a comment

Tags: graphql, github-api-v4

I am trying to get the reaction count for each content using the Github v4 API (GraphQL). Can anyone suggest how can I achieve this?

Github supports the following reactions:

```
THUMBS_UP
THUMBS_DOWN
LAUGH
HOORAY
CONFUSED
HEART
ROCKET
EYES
```

For each reaction, I want a count which denotes the number of people who reacted. For eg. I am referring to this comment -> [#2190](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github/issues/2190#issue-461960009).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Github API provides a feature called reaction group. Refer to the following query...

```
{
  repository(owner: "sindresorhus", name: "refined-github") {
    issue(number: 2190) {
      reactionGroups {
        content
        users {
          totalCount
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this solves your problem!